# How to capture repeating information with regex

Tags: regex, preg-match

I try to capture all information in a string but only the last one is captured.
I start with regex and i need some help.

The string :

> `correspondent à l'ASIN B00WU8XXXX, mais les attributs suivants sont en conflit avec : product_type (Vendeur : 'APPLIANCE_ACCESSORY' / Amazon : 'CLEANING_AGENT'), ean (Vendeur : '400650819XXXX' / Amazon : '400650819XXXX'), item_package_quantity (Vendeur : '5' / Amazon : '10'`

My regex :

```
.* (.*?) \(Vendeur : \'(.*?)\' \/ Amazon : \'(.*?)\'
```

I capture only the last block

```
item_package_quantity : 5 : 10
```

That i want to capture :

```
product_type : APPLIANCE_ACCESSORY : CLEANING_AGENT  
ean : 400650819XXXX: 400650819XXXX  
item_package_quantity : 5 : 10
```

It must be nothing but i turn around :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could start the pattern with the group 1 match for 1 or more word characters `(\w+)` and use a negated character class `[^']*` for the values inside the single quotes.

Depending on the delimiter you have to escape the `\/`

```
(\w+) \(Vendeur : '([^']*)' \/ Amazon : '([^']*)'
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/MziYTJ/1) | [PHP demo](https://3v4l.org/MhIdu)

```
$pattern = '/(\w+) \(Vendeur : \'([^\']*)\' \/ Amazon : \'([^\']*)\'/m';
$s = 'correspondent à l\'ASIN B00WU8XXXX, mais les attributs suivants sont en conflit avec : product_type (Vendeur : \'APPLIANCE_ACCESSORY\' / Amazon : \'CLEANING_AGENT\'), ean (Vendeur : \'400650819XXXX\' / Amazon : \'400650819XXXX\'), item_package_quantity (Vendeur : \'5\' / Amazon : \'10\'';

if(preg_match_all($pattern, $s, $matches, PREG_SET_ORDER)) {
    print_r(array_map(fn($m) => implode(" : ", array_slice($m, 1)), $matches));
}
```

Output

```
Array
(
    [0] => product_type : APPLIANCE_ACCESSORY : CLEANING_AGENT
    [1] => ean : 400650819XXXX : 400650819XXXX
    [2] => item_package_quantity : 5 : 10
)
```